# What is the best way to pass an object to another class in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, nsmutablearray

Really enjoying working on my first app after a couple months of non-stop studying. Been given the opportunity to do a charities iOS App. It is very basic app but I'm now stuck and would like some help.

I have the following view controllers and one class:

```
PeopleViewController (datasource and delegate, also holds "people" NSMuteable array)
PersonViewController
Person
```

I have a `PersonViewController` and this controller is connected to a view that displays a form with a few text fields and an image upload option. It has a submit button at the very bottom that is connected to an action that collects all the data from the fields. Well that's what I intend to do.

I have a `PeopleViewController` which is a `datasource` and `delegate`. It is responsible for providing a list of users to show on the table view. These list of users are taken from an array "people". Currently I am populating the array in the `viewDidLoad` method of the people view controller. Eventually the `datasource` will be the clients database but for now this array is acting as that database.

What I want to do is some how get the data from the `PersonViewController` which I have stored in a Person class instance over into the PeopleViewController array. When the submit button of the `PersonViewController` form is tapped an instance of `Person` is created and then the data from the fields is stored in that new object. The thing is that people array is populated during viewDidLoad.

Questions:

**How can I get the newly created and populated `Person` object in the `PersonViewController` into the people array in the `PeopleViewController` class?**

**What would be the best way to achieve this?**

**Am I right in saying after viewDidLoad is run the people array holding existing "people" remains present in the heap and I can just some how add this newly created object to that array?**

Slightly confused.

I have thought of a few ways but some seem quite tedious. I'd like to see how an experienced developer would do this and understand why.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your array must be an NSMutableArray, otherwise you can't add or remove objects from the array.

Once you're sure that your array is mutable, you can just call

```
[personArray addObject:newPerson];
```

You can do this, even if you fill your array in `viewDidLoad`. Note that adding an item to the array is just one step, you still need to update the user interface.

EDIT:
To pass the newly created Person object from one controller to another you have several options. If PersonViewController has a pointer to PeopleViewcontroller you can just make the array a public property.

```
[myPeopleViewController.personArray addObject...]
```

It's really hard to answer this question because I would need to see how both your ViewControllers are being instantiated, and what's their relationship one another.

Comment: Adding objects to arrays is no problem. What I meant was how do I get an new instance of an object from one controller to another.

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to expose a mutable array as a public property like that.

Comment: @Paul.s It's just a design preference. If you don't like it you can instead provide an `addItem` method instead of exposing the array, but this can sometimes be a pain, because you need to provide functions for inserting, deleting, querying...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a Singleton is interesting for you.
Especially if you will enhance your app to share data with other ViewControllers.

Here a good site to learn something about DesignPattern and Singleton
http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns

Hope thats helps you a little bit and have fun with iOS.

Greetz

Comment: Thanks definitely something I'll look into. I realise segues won't always be useful. There will be other situations where I don't wish to create another controller to push to.

Answer (score 0):

What I had done originally was have an action attached to my forms submit button. Then I declared an instance variable and initialised it inside the action. Then was under the impression I could grab the instance in my prepareforsegue method and access it's properties I had set in the action but I kept getting null when trying to read a properties from the object instance.

I deleted the action and removed it's connection then initialised a new object to store the text field values inside the prepareforsegue method and this worked fine for me.